# How to reroute my react app after an asynchronous api request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am working on rerouting my application. I have a form, I want the user to be redirected after the form is submitted successfully. I placed the logic after the api is successful. My url changes but the component that is meant to be loaded on that url does not load.

```js
import { browserHistory } from '../router/router';
...

export const storeRecord=(data)=>{
    return function(dispatch, getState){
      //console.log('state',getState());
      const {authToken, userId} = getState().authReducer;
      token= authToken;
        data.userId = userId;
        const url = 'investment/store';
        apiCall(url, data, dispatch,'post').then((data)=>{
          try{
            if(data.status=== 200){
              //let data = apiResponse.data
              console.log('success',data);
              browserHistory.push('/');
              //dispatch(push('/'));
            }
          }
          catch(error){
            console.log('returnedError',error);

          }
        }, (error)=>{console.log(error)});
        
        
    }
}
```

Here is my route as well:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
...
export const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();


const AppRouter=()=>{

    return(<Router>
        <LoaderModal />
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={LandingPage} />
            <PublicRouter path="/register" exact component={SignupPage} />
            <PublicRouter path="/login" exact component={LoginPage} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/investment/new" exact component={InvestmentForm} />
            <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
            
        </Switch>
    </Router>)
}

export default AppRouter;
```

I am using [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) for rerouting and [history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) for the browser re-routing.

Comment: can you show how have you configured your router

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I have updated my question to reflect the router config

Comment: I believe react-router's philosophy concerning redirections is that they should be declarative using the Redirect component but I may be wrong since I haven't used it in some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code in place of dispatch(push('/')) which you used in storeRecord component.

window.location.assign('/');

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same history object that your Router modules uses to dynamically Route.

The easiest solution is for you to not use browserRouter but to use a Router with custom history

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
...
export const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();


const AppRouter=()=>{

    return(<Router history={browserHistory}>
        <LoaderModal />
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={LandingPage} />
            <PublicRouter path="/register" exact component={SignupPage} />
            <PublicRouter path="/login" exact component={LoginPage} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/investment/new" exact component={InvestmentForm} />
            <Route component={NotFoundPage} />

        </Switch>
    </Router>)
}

export default AppRouter;
```

and then your action will look like

```
import { browserHistory } from '../router/router';
...

export const storeRecord=(data)=>{
    return function(dispatch, getState){
      const {authToken, userId} = getState().authReducer;
      token= authToken;
        data.userId = userId;
        const url = 'investment/store';
        apiCall(url, data, dispatch,'post').then((data)=>{
          try{
            if(data.status=== 200){
              browserHistory.push('/');
            }
          }
          catch(error){
            console.log('returnedError',error);

          }
        }, (error)=>{console.log(error)});


    }
}
```

Comment: could you please show how the code in the action would look like. Kindly note that I only want a routing to happen when the api request is successful